# Understanding the working of 'Interpolation'

Tags: pandas, missing-data, interpolation

'Interpolation' is a technique that is used to predict a null/empty value by studying its neighbouring points.

Interpolation doesn't take into consideration the entire dataset when predicting the missing value of a column. It only considers the values of the column that is being interpolated.

So, **how does this technique identify the null value's closest neighbours? How does a value that doesn't exist be considered for anything? What is its reference point?**

Comment: umm... I see a few difficulties here: (1) Clearly, you are not asking about a mathematical definition. But which kind of definition are you then using? (2) interpolation _can_ take into account the whole dataset. (3) interpolation exists independently of "columns". I'm afraid the question/problem is not well posed and needs more details.

Comment: Isn't considering other columns of the dataset 'Predictive Modeling'?

Comment: @Apoorva, the terms you are using are too broad. Terms 'predictive modelling', and 'interpolation' have many meanings for different people. You stand a better chance of getting a meaningful answer if you spend more time to expand your question. Explain what you mean by 'interpolation' as part of the question (not just a vague word technique), give an example, then ask a very specific question, and only then, perhaps generalize